# ¿Los enlaces con nofollow aportan SEO?

Tags: seo

Soy consciente de que los enlaces con nofollow se aplican concretamente para que los bots de los buscadores no siga por ese link.

La realidad es que ese link atrae visitas y mi teoría es que un enlace aunque tenga un nofollow para Google por ejemplo sigue teniendo valor aunque sea un 1% comparándolo con uno sin el nofollow.

A parte de esto, para que sirven los siguientes valores al atributo rel porque no veo información fiable sobre ello (el que me llama la atención es `external`).

Solo he visto información aquí:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_rel.asp

Pero no explica si hay diferencias en temas de SEO o comportamientos de navegador.

He creado varios links a https://japanpanda.com/ siendo nofollow (En páginas ajenas) y no he visto ningún cambio excepto mejoras en los referal.

Comment: Las visitas que lleguen desde un enlace con `nofollow` cuentan igual que cualquier otro, el tema es que nofollow se usa en gran medida para que los enlaces que salen de tu página y que puedan perjudicar tu reputación no te afecten, por eso se suele añadir a los enlaces que pone la gente en los comentarios de un blog ya que esos enlaces no los controlas tú.

Comment: el valor external no aparece en la especificación y los navagadores no lo usan para nada, no sé si para los buscadores tiene alguna función. Yo alguna vez lo he usado para dar un estilo diferente a los enlaces que van fuera de mi sitio con el selector css `a[rel=external]`. No sabría decirte si tiene alguna otra función

Comment: Usar ese selector para darle un estilo diferente es una muy buena idea ¡gracias por la inspiración!

Comment: Con el `nofollow` el buscador no va a registrar ese enlace como un backlink. Se podria decir que el enlace puede ayudar en el SEO del dominio que lo utiliza, pero no para el dominio que lo recibe. Esa ayuda no seria más que semántica, ayudando al SEO en el aspecto de tener contenidos semánticos y completos (si se utiliza correctamente, claro). Por otro lado el dominio receptor no se va a beneficiar en SEO por el backlink, ya que no será considerado como tal. Pero podemos decir que indirectamente sí ayuda al SEO al traer visitas aumentando así el Page Authority y Domain Authority del sitio web.

Comment: Yo me pregunto si cuando hablamos de SEO nos referimos exclusivamente a Google. Es el buscador mayoritario con bastante diferencia pero hay otros que usan diferentes algoritmos y una búsqueda en google o en duckduckgo, por ejemplo, no devuelve los mismos resultados. Volviendo a `nofollow` parece que casi todos los buscadores evitan dar puntos en sus clasificaciones de páginas a estos enlaces, sin embargo casi todos los siguen, se supone que google ni les da pagerank ni los sigue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sobre los valores que puede tener `rel` en un enlace, puedes leer más en la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Tipos_de_enlaces) (parcialmente en español al momento de escribir esta respuesta) o directamente en la documentación del W3C para el [estándar HTML5](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#sec-link-types) y el elemento `a` (en inglés).

Lo que indica `rel` es la relación entre el documento que contiene el enlace y el documento enlazado. **No afecta a cómo representará el navegador esos enlaces**, aunque puede ser usado en el selector de atributo en CSS (ej: `a[rel="valor"]`) para darles algún estilo específico.

Para el SEO ayuda a darle sentido (semántica) a la página y puede ser de ayuda para hacer ingeniería social (por ejemplo especificando el autor) o para clasificar/indexar mejor los contenidos y sus relaciones con otras páginas/sitios.

Ahora voy a entrar un poco más en detalle del `nofollow` y del `external`.

---

**`nofollow`**

Lo primero que habría que aclarar es que `nofollow` no quiere decir que los bots de los motores de búsqueda no vayan a seguir el enlace, de hecho, lo más probable es que lo vayan a seguir. Según la [definición de HTML5](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#link-type-nofollow) (traducción mía):

> La palabra clave `nofollow` indica que el enlace no está avalado por el autor o editor original de la página, o que el enlace al documento referenciado fue incluido principalmente por una relación comercial entre personas afiliadas a ambas páginas.

Teniendo eso en cuenta, ponerle un `nofollow` a un enlace no afectará al tráfico del destino (el enlace puede ser visitado por los usuarios) ni a su descubrimiento por parte de los motores de búsqueda (lo de no seguir es una "recomendación" para el bot) pero, como bien dicen en los comentarios, sí puede afectar (negativamente) a la página que contiene el enlace. **La clasificación de una página va a depender en parte del análisis de los sitios enlazados en esa página**.

Por ejemplo, si un motor de búsqueda considera que la "Página Z" es mala porque tiene spam y spyware, y tu "Página Y" tiene un enlace a esa "Página Z", entonces ese motor de búsqueda va a penalizarte por enlazar a una página que sabe que es mala. Por eso es importante usar `nofollow` en algunos enlaces.

Como regla general, la recomendación sería que no te fíes de ningún enlace que venga de una entrada de usuario (por ejemplo en los comentarios de un blog o en las respuestas de un foro) y le añadas `nofollow` para ahorrarte problemas.

En este [artículo de Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=es) (en español) se mencionan tres casos importantes en los que usar `nofollow` es bueno y recomendable:

- **Si no confías en el contenido enlazado**. Básicamente por lo dicho arriba, para "*evitar transferir valores de PageRank inconscientemente a los "vecindarios indeseables" de la Web*". También se menciona como método para disuadir a los distribuidores de spam (pudiendo quitar el `nofollow` manualmente para enlaces que hayas comprobado).
- **Si es un enlace de pago**. Los motores de búsqueda quieren que los enlaces de pago/comerciales sean identificados y lo valoran, "*del mismo modo que los consumidores online y tradicionales valoran que se revelen las relaciones comerciales (por ejemplo, cuando el anuncio de un periódico incluye el encabezado 'Anuncio')*"
- **Para dar prioridad de rastreo**. Por ejemplo, para que los bots no sigan los enlaces a secciones de "regístrate aquí" o "inicia sesión", porque "*los robots de los motores de búsqueda no pueden acceder o registrarse como miembros de tu foro*".

---

**`external`**

En el caso particular del valor `external` lo que se está diciendo es que el documento/página enlazada es un sitio diferente. Si el usuario lo pulsa, abandonará el sitio actual para navegar a otro diferente.

No te va a afectar en lo que se refiere a SEO, sólo añade algo de información semántica (aunque no sé realmente cuál es el valor de esa información porque el motor de búsqueda va a detectar automáticamente si el enlace es externo o no).

Por los comentarios que he encontrado buscando online, parece que en el pasado algunos navegadores trataban `rel="external"` como si fuese un `target="_blank"` y habrían el enlace en una nueva ventana (aunque no he encontrado nada oficial sobre eso).

Comment: Muy buena información, gracias!

Comment: La respuesta es buena pero creo que no acaba de completar la pregunta que es ¿Aporta valor a nivel de SEO que tu web esté enlazada en 2000 sitios pero siendo esos links rel="nofollow"?

Comment: @DanielDíaz Que un enlace tenga `nofollow` en otro sitio web no afecta en nada a tu sitio web, afecta al de origen. Como pongo en la respuesta, los bots van a seguir indexando el destino, por lo que van a seguir contando que tienes 2000 sitios enlazándote, sin importarles si el enlace de origen tiene o no el `rel="nofollow"`

Comment: Eso es lo que pongo en duda, en muchos artículos comentan que tener muchos enlaces `nofollow` aportan posiciones en el "ranking SEO" de buscadores como Google. Ej. http://www.seoagencias.com/enlaces-nofollow/

Comment: No sé si consideraría esa como una fuente fiable. El artículo contiene incorrecciones (confunde destino con origen y parece no comprender como los bots rastrean los nofollow). Además, es más una teoría que algo basado en hechos objetivos; sólo la frase "_A diferencia de la mayoría pienso que [...]_" hace sonar muchas alarmas.

Comment: Tener muchos enlaces te da posiciones en el ranking, que sean `dofollow` o `nofollow` te debería ser irrelevante mientras tu contenido sea bueno. Que el enlace tenga `nofollow` al que afecta es al origen (la página que te enlaza) y no a ti (la página de destino)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, en teoría sí que afectan los enlaces `nofollow` a la página de destino. La mayoría de los buscadores no suman reputación a la página enlazada si el enlace es `nofollow`, otra cosa serán las visitas que lleguen de esos enlaces, las visitas cuentan igual lleguen de donde lleguen. De cualquier forma los algorítmos de los buscadores van cambiando y en general no dan mucha información sobre como funcionan.

Comment: Yo pongo en duda que los enlaces `nofollow` den posiciones en el ranking. Creo que solo dan tráfico referal...

Comment: Por la polémica que ha generado y el punto al que hemos llegado te otorgo la recompensa. Creo que es un tema que no está claro 100% y que tampoco se puede afirmar a ciencia cierta si otorga ranking o no.

Answer (score 0):

Todos los enlaces aportan valor. Los enlaces do follow son los mejores, pero si solo tenemos enlaces do follow a una web sería muy sospechoso. Por eso es bueno mezclarlos.
Aquí te dejo unas herramientas para saber si son do follow o no follow:

https://www.informacionyarte.com/analizar-backlinks

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score -1):

Los enlaces nofollow, si estan bien ubicados, tienen un cierto valor. Generan tráfico al sitio lo cual, indirectamente, ayuda con el rango de la página.

Ver: https://moz.com/blog/the-hidden-power-of-nofollow-links

Comment: Hablamos de SEO, no de "rango de página" que creo que ni existe

Comment: Creo que el PR si existe, pero que Google ya no lo divulga mas, como ha dejado de divulgar tantas cosas.

Comment: Ver: https://moz.com/community/q/is-pagerank-still-a-ranking-factor-for-google

Comment: Lo siento pero los enlaces nofollow no aportan PR para nada, no tiene nada que ver.