# Uso del atributo rel en los enlaces de un sitio o aplicación web

Tags: html, relaciones

Al desarrollar con *React* el navegador muestra esta advertencia:

> Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security
>   risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener 
>   react/jsx-no-target-blank

El enlace lleva a una página que ejemplifica porque no incluir los atributos `noopener noreferrer` puede suponer un riesgo de seguridad para los visitantes de nuestro sitio web y las pertinentes recomendaciones.

Todo esto me ha llevado a consultar este [listado de **posibles valores que puede adoptar el atributo `rel` de un *tag* `a` de HTML**](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_rel.asp) y este [otro](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-a-rel-attribute/):

```
alternate
author
bookmark
external
help
license
next
nofollow
noreferrer
noopener
prev
search
tag
```

y a darme cuenta de que no le estaba dando a este atributo la importancia debida al significado y/o utilidad que puede aportar a los enlaces de un sitio web, según como y donde se usan o dejan de usar. Por ejemplo, yo uso habitualmente un `nofollow` en los enlaces a otras páginas que añado en mis sitios. Esto a veces no es necesario... si enlazo otro sitio propio relacionado. ¿No sería mejor poner `rel="nofollow external"` o `nofollow` acompañado de otros valores? ¿Se puede usar más de uno de forma conjunta?
¿Que factores debemos tener en cuenta?

Hilo con detalles sobre el [uso de nofollow y external](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31561).

***Nota:*** en cuanto a usar varias propiedades de forma consulta el [validator del W3](https://validator.w3.org/) lo da por bueno.

Comment: No se a que te refieras pero según entiendo ¿Quieres saber si **se puede agregar mas de un atributo en un mismo `rel`**? Si se puede, un ejemplo sería `rel="noopener nofollow noreferrer"`

Comment: Ya no me acordaba de cuando puse esta pregunta... Antaño usaba un `rel="nofollow"` para casi todos los enlaces externos. Claro las cosas van cambiando y me llamo la atención la cantidad de valores que podía agregar cuando me puse a mirar esto. A "grandes rasgos" creo contestas a mi pregunta, pero también quería saber las implicaciones que tiene usar diferentes combinaciones, ya que estos atributos implican cuestiones de seguridad, usabilidad, SEO, ...